# JSON Key name with spaces

Tags: c#, json, ssis

I am getting a JSON file in the format below which i am trying to consume and upload to SQL Server, I can upload most data except for any key with spaces in the name, like below Location (Last Level), I have 36 records in the JSON file and SSIS created 36 records in the SQL table but Location (Last Level) is blank, if I Country just to test it works and populate the table with correct values, I am only interested in **Location (Last Level)**:

```
"records": [
        {
            "Location (Last Level)": "Calgary",
            "Country": "Canada"

        },
        {
            "Location (Last Level)": "Coconut Creek",
            "Country": "United States"

        },
```

I created a class for this:

```
namespace SC_0fc0e19fc563441a96856fc8e8911872
{
    public class LocAPI
    {
        
        public string LocationLastLevel { get; set; }
        
    }
    public class Root
    {

        public List<LocAPI> records { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I am not sure how do I consume or refer to JSON keys with spaces in the name like Location (Last Level).
Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Update: I have change the class a little bit based on another thread but still didnt work:

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace SC_0fc0e19fc563441a96856fc8e8911872
{
    public class LocAPI
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("Location (Last Level)")]
        public string LocationLastLevel { get; set; }
        
    }
    public class Root
    {

        public List<LocAPI> records { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Main:

```
var response = client.GetAsync(APIUrl).Result;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            
            Root loc = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Root>(result);

            foreach (var item in loc.records)
            {

                
                LocationAPIBuffer.AddRow();

                LocationAPIBuffer.Location = item.LocationLastLevel;
                
                
            }
```

Comment: Add this code  using System.Text.Json and replace JavaScriptSerializer with  Root loc = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(Root).Result;